Writing COPC is not supported - Laspy
I have a simple code
import laspy
las = laspy.read('data/segmented.las')
old_class = las.classification
las.classification = new_class
las.write('data/segmented_5.las')

But this gives an error
NotImplementedError: Writing COPC is not supported

I have also tried saving the file as 'copc.laz', 'copz.las' neither works.
I have also ensured both the new_class and old_class are same data types - uint8
My versions are:

laspy==2.5.3
lazrs==0.5.3


Do I understand right that you are not interested in COPC but you just want to save your data into basic .las format?

@user30184 yes just the basic .las format will also work

It seems to be that when a COPC file is opened with laspy, it remembers that the data are from COPC, and laspy tries to create a COPC also on writing. However, that is not supported https://github.com/laspy/laspy/blob/dcf0ff076fd801e768a9138d71f28da611ed8c8f/laspy/copc.py#L151. There must a way to read just the points from COPC and write them into a normal las/laz file, but unfortunately my trials were not successful.

I made a test with this COPC file https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/PDAL/data/master/autzen/autzen-classified.copc.laz?download=true by using a modified COPC example code from the laspy documentation https://laspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#copc
import laspy
las = laspy.read('autzen-classified.copc.laz')
points = las.points.copy()
new_header = laspy.LasHeader(
            version=las.header.version,
            point_format=las.header.point_format
        )
new_header.offsets = las.header.offsets
new_header.scales = las.header.scales
with laspy.open(f"output_las.las", mode="w", header=new_header) as f:
            f.write_points(points)

At least a new .las file gets written without the "Writing COPC is not supported" error.
